# How to query to show only posts of the last week

Tags: graphql, drupal-8, gatsby

In my drupal 8 decoupled project with Gatsby I want to filter with a graphql query posts. I am using the json-api module.
I only want in Gatsby the output of a query for posts of the last week. So I need something like:

```
allNodePosts(filter: {date: {eq: "between today and last seven days"}}) {
  edges {
    node {
      body {
        value
      }
    }
  }
```

Is this possible with graphql? And if yes how must the query looks like?

Comment: GraphQL does not support filtering by itself. It's up to the individual service to implement things like filtering, sorting, pagination, etc. If this question pertains to a particular framework or library that uses GraphQL, like Gatsby, Strapi, etc. or if you are querying a specific public API, please edit your question to provide that information.

Comment: @DanielRearden That is an interesting information. So I have edit my question. Thanks